# Как ссылаться на файл(имея любое название с любое расширением)

Tags: php, javascript, html

Добрый день.
Как можно открыть файл с любое название и с любим расширением 
у меня файл стоит на папку document/file.doc типа document/*.* как то так?

```
<a href="document/*.*">
```

Цель такого. Я добавляю файл в папку document/id/ где после данного id стоит файл например (document/99/test.doc) но файлы они у меня имеют разные название с разными расширениями и через php я должен ссылаться на файл типа

```
<a href="document/$id/test.doc">
```

типа так

```
<a href="document/$id/*.*"
```

Comment: <a href="document/file.doc">

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Добавьте знаки препинания, напишите подробнее чем именно нужно открывать, если уже есть наработки, приведите части кода!

Comment: Цель такого. Я добавляю файл в папку document/id/ где после данного id стоит файл например (document/99/test.doc) но файлы они у меня имеют разные название с разными расширениями и через php  я должен ссылаться на файл типа <a href="document/$id/test.doc"> типа так <a href="document/$id/*.*">

Comment: Путем несколькоразчтения стала понятна суть вопроса... Даже код написал, а вопрос закрыли(

Comment: @GrayHoax открыли, чтобы тут же закрыть с указанием другой причины :)

Comment: Блин, вот я пару часов назад закрыл notepad++ с кодом(((( Принцип описал в копии вопроса...